# Read all characters written in FIFO using open() system call

Tags: c, fifo

I have a FIFO pipe, which is opened at both ends using open() in O_RDWR mode. At the reading end, read() is not reading all the characters, but lesser than that specified in the call. Is there a way to ensure that all characters are read using open()?

Thanks in advance

```
if (p != NULL){

        printf("Inside p not null!\n");

        if((fd = open(p, O_RDWR)) < 0){
            perror("File could not be opened!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //FILE *rdptr = fopen(p,"r");

        memset(buf,0,file_len);
        rc = read(fd, buf, file_len);
        printf("Number of bytes read: %d\n", rc);

        printf("Data detected on FIFO\n");
                buf[rc] = '\0';
                char base[20] = "output.txt";
                char name[20];
                sprintf(name, "%d%s", suffix, base);
        FILE *fptr = fopen(name,"ab+");
        fd_wr = open(name,O_WRONLY);
        charnum = write(fd_wr,buf,rc);
        kill(id_A, SIGKILL);
        //printf("No. of characters written: %d\n",charnum);
                //FD_CLR(fd, &rdfs);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `read()` again for reading the remaining characters?

Comment: No, I am just reading it once. The code is added in the edited post. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: If you're writing a fixed amount of data then killing the writer, why don't you just use a file instead? It seems you don't need a FIFO here.

Comment: No, actually each writer has to write to a separate FIFO,which is read by the process above, and then it kills the writer. The FIFO is a part of the requirement. I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

First minor comment: you should use `O_RDONLY` to open the file: don't use more permissions than necessary.

Second issue: if `file_len` is very large, it's possible that the writer has blocked trying to write the entire chunk of data (since a FIFO can only hold a certain amount of unread data). If that's the case, then `read` will only read the data that has been stored in the FIFO, and will immediately return with whatever it could read. This will allow the writer to write more bytes, which will then be read in the next `read`.

You should loop reads, adjusting an offset into the buffer, until the entire `file_len` bytes are read. Something like this:

```
size_t offset = 0;
while(offset < file_len) {
    rc = read(fd, buf+offset, file_len-offset);
    if(rc < 0) {
        /* handle I/O error or something... */
    } else {
        offset += rc;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i couldn't format it properly, but is that what you mean?

Comment: No. `read` will produce some partial output, and you have to *increment* the offset to read more. (It's like reading a book: you start where you left off, not from the beginning again).

Comment: With that code, I am trying to print rc after exiting the while loop, but it never does so. It seems the loop is not exiting, maybe because read is blocked or something.

Comment: is there a way to "flush" a FIFO maybe? I don't know if that's the right term to use.